# Quotes "" appearing above PHP include

Tags: php, wordpress, include, wordpress-theming

I am currently making a 'bulky' Wordpress theme, trying to use `<?php include(); ?>` to lessen the size of the core files.

I tried wrapping it in several different elements with no change in result.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <?php include('blah.php');?>
</div>
```

blah.php

```
<div class="blah-wrap">
    <p>The content</p>
</div>
```

gives HTML Output:

```
<div id="wrap">
 "
 "
<div class="blah-wrap">
    <p>The Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Those quotes appear regardless of the content of blah.php, or where blah.php is included. I wouldn't normally care, however it is adding a space above where I include the file - about 1em - which is messing with the design.

Is there a reason why it's acting like a `&nbsp;` is present and wrapping it in the quotes?
Or whatever it may be, my html structure is perfect, it's not a problem.

Comment: Is this really the whole content of `blah.php`? Could you also post some lines from before and after `<div id="wrap">`?

Comment: Indeed, go through all the files which are included by blah.php and check for stray characters at the start or end. If you have trouble finding it, then you could always use `ob_start` and `ob_get_contents` to slowly isolate the source.

Comment: I didn't include the entire content of "blah.php" because no matter what the contents, if it includes a spec of html, it happens. If no html is present and just plain text, it's inserted into the quotes. No files are included by blah.php itself.

Comment: @William You should give us more source code, even if you think it is irrelevant because the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'd agree -- with your code as stated, William, I can't see how your problem could happen, so we'll need to see more code. What's the minimum *actual code* you can reproduce the problem with, including real class names, etc? Which template file is your HTML code in? And how are you inspecting the HTML? Also: is there a possibility that a WordPress plugin is interfering with your output?

Comment: looking at 991 lines of code in the "blah.php" alone it will be unpractical and too demanding of me to ask any of you to sort through this, since the problem seems to be a freak occurrence I will find another way to include blah.php efficiently without that bloody space appearing before the include. Thanks for responding, Quasdunk, Andrea, Karolis.

Comment: What WP plugins do you have installed? It's not too uncommon for a poorly developed one to screw with things.

Comment: Fixed it, it was the encoding of the php file. I was using notepad utf-8, saved it from Word pad and No more white space! Don't know why this was the cause but it is definitely the encoding that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the blah.php file is a custom template file that you wanna include in your theme, regardless of whether the residing content of the file is dynamically generated from the Wordpress system (post loop) or hard coded into the file you should be using this instead:

```
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/blah.php');?>
```

I stand to be corrected, but I highly suspect that the reason the quotation marks are appearing is because using `<?php include('blah.php');?>` means that there is no path defined for Wordpress to understand or grab. And though the file may be loaded in, Wordpress might just be trying to resolve the path to the file but cannot do so, thus giving an output of the quotation marks with nothing in it. The TEMPLATEPATH is Wordpress function and generally consist of the URL to your template directory (e.g. http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/template-folder).

Comment: oops. my bad, didn't see that this problem has been resolved. but well, just my two cents' worth.